# Before Trigger for SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, triggers

I am a student doing a project in SQL Server 2005. I am trying to write a procedure to generate and insert a primary key for an ID. I thought of a before insert trigger but I am getting errors. Can someone help me.. This is what I came up with so far:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Create_ResourceID
ON Resource
before INSERT
AS
   DECLARE @resourceid  INT
   SELECT @resourceid  = (max(ResourceID) + 1) FROM Resource
GO

INSERT INTO Resource(ResourceID) VALUES (@resourceid);
```

Comment: What error are you getting? By the way, I think you need to indent the first line of your code (starting `CREATE TRIGGER` but I can't edit in the indent because StackOverflow tells me I need to change at least 6 characters, and the indent is only 4!

Comment: SQL Server doesn't have any `BEFORE` triggers. Just don't exist. You need to use a `INSTEAD OF INSERT` trigger instead.

Comment: Why wouldn't you use an [`IDENTITY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775(v=sql.90).aspx) column?  It avoids all of the variations on a race condition that you seem to be destined to experience.  No trigger is needed, and the value assigned is available using [`SCOPE_IDENTITY()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315(v=sql.90).aspx) or an [`OUTPUT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564(v=sql.90).aspx) clause.  (_Do_ take the time to learn about OUTPUT.)

Answer (score 1):

Must you use a trigger to do this?

Simplest thing is to get SQL Server to set the primary key ID for you, something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Resource (
    ResourceID int identity,
    .
    .
    .
)
```

Comment: So if I create my table and make the ResourceID an int Identify, then when there is an insert statement, if will create and enter the ResourceID automatically? The reason I am asking is because I am building an application in Visual Studio 2008 that a user will enter data and the data will be inserted into the table. Will and identity type take care of this?

Comment: Yes, but it's `IDENTITY`. See [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms186775%28v=sql.90%29.aspx]. If you simply want a number to uniquely identify each row in the table, `IDENTITY` will do it for you.